# Powershell Regex extract concat text

Tags: regex, powershell, concatenation

I tried to extract regex string as per below code and its working fine. As per below script, it is extracting strings inside text say "45 \345\ 54" as \345\ .

```
$input_path = "E:\DOC\all.txt"
$output_file = "E:\DOC\all-pts.txt"
$regex1 = ‘[ \b\t\n\r]+\\+[A-Z0-9_-]+\\$’
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex1 -AllMatches | % { 
$_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

But when i want to extract one more regex string and concat both the regex result using if statement as per below example i am not able to do. Don't know what mistake i am making here. I new to powershell.

INPUT FILE(all.txt)

**temp1.txt**: file not found \xyz\ not found \123\
**temp2.txt**: text \ABC\ is here
**temp2.txt**: NUM \999\ yes \FIRST\

OUTPUT FILE(all-pts.txt)

**temp1.txt** \xyz\
**temp1.txt** \123\
**temp2.txt** \ABC\
**temp2.txt** \999\
**temp2.txt** \FIRST\

```
$input_path = "E:\DOC\all.txt"
$output_file = "E:\DOC\all-pts.txt"
(Get-Content "$input_path") | ForEach-Object 
{if($_ -like ‘[ \b\t\n\r]+\\+[A-Z0-9_-]+\\$’)

       {
            $regex1 = ‘[ \b\t\n\r]+\\+[A-Z0-9_-]+\\$’
            $regex2 = ‘[ A-Z0-9_-]+\.txt$’
            select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex1 -AllMatches | % 
            { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
            select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex2 -AllMatches | % 
            { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
            }
       }
```

Comment: `-like` is for wildcards (e.g. `?`/`*`).  You want to use `-match` or `-cmatch` for case-sensitive regex

Comment: The problem is I am not able to concat two regex result in same line as per output file.

Comment: Why not combine the regex then?  `'[ \b\t\n\r]+\\+[A-Z0-9_-]+\\$|[ A-Z0-9_-]+\.txt$'`

Answer (score 1):

I don't like my not universal solution with two REs.
It gets one or two occurences of values enclosed in backslashes.

```
$input_path =  ".\all.txt"
$output_file = ".\all-pts.txt"

$RE1 = "(?<Pat1>\\[^\\]+\\)"
$RE2 = "(?<Pat1>\\[^\\]+\\)[^\\]+(?<Pat2>\\[^\\]+\\)"

Get-Content $input_path | ForEach-Object {
    $Line = $_ -split(':')
    If ($Line[1] -Match $RE2){
        "{0} {1}" -f $line[0],$Matches.Pat1
        "{0} {1}" -f $line[0],$Matches.Pat2
    } ElseIf ($Line[1] -Match $RE1) {
        "{0} {1}" -f $line[0],$Matches.Pat1
    }
} | Set-Content $output_file
```

Sample output:

```
> gc .\all-pts.txt
temp1.txt \xyz\
temp1.txt \123\
temp2.txt \ABC\
temp2.txt \999\
temp2.txt \FIRST\
```